# Docker Swarm security best practice

Tags: docker, swarm

I am trying to create my docker swarm environment and my goal is to have all the best security practice related to docker swarm.
I am not really able to find everything I want about swarm security on topics like :
Authentification,
Encryption,
Users and Groups,
Files permission,
Logs,
Among others.

Do any of you have nice ressources where I can find all the information ?
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

Docker swarm is just an orchestration tool, in order to get a secure cluster running you just need to follow the best practices regarding Docker itself (for example, do not run containers as root user).

Check out docker secrets https://docs.docker.com/engine/swarm/secrets/ to keep secrets out of the config yaml files.

You've asked a very broad question and most of the things you mentioned are dependant on the application running in Docker.